# Error al crear matriz de booleanos. Java

Tags: java, array, booleano

Estoy haciendo un método que reciba como parámetro el número de renglones y el número de columnas de la matriz. El método deberá declarar, construir e inicializar cada casilla de esta matriz a false. Este el mi código:

```java
public void matriz(int filas, int columnas){
    boolean [][] m = new boolean [filas][columnas];
    for(int i=0; i<=m.length; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<=m[i].length; j++){
            m[i][j]=false;
        }
    }
    Arrays.asList(m).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
}
```

El método principal es así

```java
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int f=3,c=3;
    metod n=new metod();
    n.matriz(f,c);
}
```

Sin embargo a la hora de iniciar el programa me sale en siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
    at examen2.metod.matriz(metod.java:20)
```

metod.java es mi clase y 20 seria la linea que contiene esta parte de código:

```
m[i][j]=false;
```

Ojala puedan ayudarme y gracias de antemano.

Comment: En java, un arreglo de `n` posiciones tiene elementos del `0` a `n - 1`. El error está en la condición de salida del `for`, que debiera ser `i < m.length` y no `i <= m.length`, por la razón arriba indicada. Por otro lado, un arreglo de booleanos es automáticamente inicializado en falso al ser declarado, por lo que inicializarlo está de más. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Este error se produce por las condiciones de tu bucle `for (i<=m.length)`

El problema es que los `arrays` empiezan por el número `0`, por lo tanto si el parámetro "filas" del método es 3 cuando el contador `i` sea 3 la condición del `for` se cumplirá ya que es igual al tamaño del `array` (`m.length`).

Por ejemplo, si enviamos como parámetro **`filas = 3`** y **`columnas = 2`**, cuando el contador `i` sea 3 la condición se cumplirá e intentará asignar el valor `false` por ejemplo a la posición `m[3][0]` que no existe.

El problema se soluciona quitando el igual de la condición, quedaría: `i < m.length`

```
public void matriz(int filas, int columnas) {

    boolean[][] m = new boolean[filas][columnas];

    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m[i].length; j++) {
            m[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    Arrays.asList(m).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(s)));
}
```

Comment: Buenas respuesta. Yo añadiría que quien pregunta podría simplificar fijando el criterio de parada de los `for` contra las variables que recibe el método `matriz`, es decir, `filas` y `columnas`.